# PrimeFaces Gmap tag ignore model issuse

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, ejb

I have problem using gmap in primefaces 6.0 ,i try to use primefaces example inside this URL www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/markers.xhtml

my code exactly the same but nothing show on the map

```
<script type="text/javascript"  
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey">
```

```
@ManagedBean
public class MarkersView implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private MapModel simpleModel;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    simpleModel = new DefaultMapModel();

    //Shared coordinates
    LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648);
    LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);
    LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);
    LatLng coord4 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);

    //Basic marker
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki"));
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
}

public MapModel getSimpleModel() {
    return simpleModel;
}
}
```

i also try add Polylines,Polygons,Circles,Rectangle...etc , but nothing show on the map 
i test other component like buttons,input,grwl..etc everything work fine with ejb 
only problem with the gmap model

i wonder if it's bug with primefaces

Comment: do you have also the same tag with same coords as in example?

Comment: yes everything the same

Answer (score 0):

eh find solution but still i cant understand why ?

i change my code to

```
@ManagedBean
public class MarkersView implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private MapModel simpleModel;


public MarkersView() {
    simpleModel = new DefaultMapModel();

    //Shared coordinates
    LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(36.879466, 30.667648);
    LatLng coord2 = new LatLng(36.883707, 30.689216);
    LatLng coord3 = new LatLng(36.879703, 30.706707);
    LatLng coord4 = new LatLng(36.885233, 30.702323);

    //Basic marker
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "Konyaalti", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord2, "Ataturk Parki", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow-dot.png"));
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord3, "Karaalioglu Parki", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord4, "Kaleici", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"));
}



public MapModel getSimpleModel() {
    return simpleModel;
}
}
```

it's work fine show marker but didn't change marker look from URL 
anyone understand why this code work and the first didn't?